# Bash, printing after output on new

Tags: bash, utf-8, locale

Alright, So lately Ive been running into this a couple of times
If one would run `echo 'G1o=' | base64 -d` in a terminal you'd get
`username@hostname:~$62;9;c`

I think it has something to do with the locale , but is it 'normal' behavior that it puts it 'after' the output of a command ?

Comment: Wow, crazy.  All I can tell you is that the base64 encoding of that string is `1b 5a`, or `ESC Z` in ASCII.  The escape character must be blowing the shell's (or the terminal's) mind.  Maybe someone will have a good answer for you.

Comment: Jupp, I only noticed because I had some macro typing in cygwin. Once it would cat / echo whatever data with this content it would ruin my macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base64 `G1o=` decodes to hex `1B 5a`, which is <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>. That's the `DECID` escape-sequence, which back in the days when terminals were not actually part of the computer but rather devices connected through a serial cable, was the way the computer could ask the terminal what it was exactly. (That's not actually a standard; it was a private code implemented by terminals manufactured by DEC; hence DEC IDentification. DEC stands for Digital Equipment Corporation, notable for making what was possibly the first desktop computer, the PDP-8, a machine I had the pleasure of learning to code for when I was a teenager.)

Oddly, terminal emulators still support this stuff, so if you write ESC-Z to a terminal program, it will respond by telling you what sort of historical terminal it is vaguely pretending to be. For example, if you were to do that in the Linux console, it would respond: `ESC [ ? 6 c` which is the code for a DEC VT-102.

(By the way, your terminal emulator is apparently responding `ESC [ ? 62;9 c` which is the code for a VT-220 with a variety of extended "National Replacement Character" sets -- that's the `;9` part.)

Comment: Thank you for this thorough explaination. It was not realy a problem, but I coudln't get this of my mind.

Comment: @user2693011: No worries. If you feel that it addresses your question, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you consider 'normal'. All programs are set of 0 and 1 arrange in special order. Apparently, 'G' and '1' in `base64` are 'enter' and 'end of line' respectively. To confirm this just change the sequence to any other.

Comment: Presumably, OP is using an ASCII machine, and neither 'enter' nor 'end of line' are the names of any ASCII characters. What is it you're trying to get at?

Comment: I was using a macro from windows sending keys to cygwin (nothing important), the script included using cat to display some files. the problem is that the shell actualy executes the blaberish after outputed. I'm using utf8 though.